# How to find the derivative of $x{^2/3} - (x - 1)^{1/3}$ by the limit calculation?

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

*I had to solve an exercise and was going to ask for help here, but as I typed, I spotted an error myself. I felt sorry to throw away all that MathJax stuff I typed for more than an hour, so I decided to post the question anyway, since it still can be useful to someone. If someone has any suggestions, corrections, I would be very grateful.*

This is the task itself, which I'd like to quote, at least for search engines to index, if someone else has this problem.

> Graph the curves in Exercises 39-48.
>
> a. Where do the graphs appear to have vertical tangent lines?
>
> b. Confirm your findings in part (a) with limit calculations …

---

**The problem itself:**

I can't solve exercise 45: $y = x^{2/3} - (x - 1)^{1/3}$.

I would be grateful if someone told me how to solve this exactly, but any help or hint will be greatly appreciated.

I need to find the derivative of this function, but by limit calculations. I know, the derivative should be $\frac{2}{3x^{1/3}} - \frac{1}{3(x- 1)^{2/3}}$, but I can't find it through the limit:

$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{(x + h)^{2/3} - (x - 1 + h)^{1/3} - x^{2/3} + (x- 1)^{1/3}}{h}
$$

---

**Tried approach 1:**

I tried to split the fraction in four ones, multiply both the nominator and denominator by a power of nominator necessary to get rid of the cubic root, like:

$$
\frac{x + h}{h(x + h)^{1/3}}
$$

But this didn't help, since dangling '*h*'s were still remaining in the expressions and I needed to combine the four fractions into a single one again, thus multiplying the nominators by cubic roots again.

---

**Tried approach 2:**

This one actually worked, and I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's split the limit fraction in two ones:

$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{(x + h)^{2/3} - (x - 1 + h)^{1/3} - x^{2/3} + (x- 1)^{1/3}}{h} = \\
\lim_{h \to 0} (\frac{(x + h)^{2/3} - x^{2/3}}{h} - \frac{(x- 1)^{1/3} - (x - 1 + h)^{1/3} }{h})
$$

For simplicity let's deal with the fractions without the limit notation:

$$
\frac{(x + h)^{2/3}- x^{2/3}}{h} \text{let's call it the left part} - \frac{(x- 1)^{1/3} - (x - 1 + h)^{1/3}}{h} \text{let's call it the right part}
$$

I multiplied both the left and right parts to make the nominators become differences of the cubes (to get rid of the cubic roots).

The left part turned to be this:

$$
\require{cancel}
\frac{(x + h)^2 - x^2}{h((x + h)^{4/3} + x^{2/3}(x + h)^{2/3} + x^{4/3})} = \\
\frac{\cancel{x^2} + 2\cancel{h}x + \cancelto{h}{h^2} - \cancel{x^2}}{\cancel{h}((x + h)^{4/3} + x^{2/3}(x + h)^{2/3} + x^{4/3})} = \\
\frac{2x + h}{(x + h)^{4/3} + x^{2/3}(x + h)^{2/3} + x^{4/3}}
$$

the right part:

$$
\require{cancel}
\frac{\cancel{x} - \cancel{1} - \cancel{x} + \cancel{1} - \cancelto{1}{h}}{\cancel{h}((x - 1)^{2/3} + (x - 1)^{1/3}(x - 1 + h)^{1/3} + (x - 1 + h)^{2/3})} = \\
\frac{- 1}{(x - 1)^{2/3} + (x - 1)^{1/3}(x - 1 + h)^{1/3} + (x - 1 + h)^{2/3}}
$$

Since the *h* tends to 0, the limit is:

$$
\require{cancel}
\lim_{h \to 0}(\frac{2x + \cancelto{0}{h}}{(x + \cancelto{0}{h})^{4/3} + x^{2/3}(x + \cancelto{0}{h})^{2/3} + x^{4/3}} - \frac{1}{(x - 1)^{2/3} + (x - 1)^{1/3}(x - 1 + \cancelto{0}{h})^{1/3} + (x - 1 + \cancelto{0}{h})^{2/3}}) = \\
\frac{2x}{x^{4/3} + x^{2/3}x^{2/3} + x^{4/3}} - \frac{1}{(x - 1)^{2/3} + (x - 1)^{1/3}(x - 1)^{1/3} + (x - 1)^{2/3}} = \\
\frac{2\cancel{x}}{3\cancelto{x^{1/3}}{x^{4/3}}} - \frac{1}{3(x - 1)^{2/3}} = \\
\frac{2}{3x^{1/3}} - \frac{1}{3(x - 1)^{2/3}}
$$